# Trying to select rows in a table, always getting NavigableString error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying unsuccessfully to scrape a list of countries and altitudes from a wiki page:

Here's the relevant HTML from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_average_elevation):

```
<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
```

And here's my code

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_average_elevation"
soup = BeautifulSoup(read_url(url), 'html.parser')

table = soup.find("table", {"class":"wikitable"})
tbody = table.find("tbody")   
rows = tbody.find("tr") <---this gives the error, saying tbody is None

countries = []
altitudes = []

for row in rows:
    cols = row.findAll('td')
    for td in cols:
        if td.a:
            countries.append(td.a.text)
        elif "m (" in td.text:
            altitudes.append(float(td.text.split("m")[0].replace(",", "")))
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wiki.py", line 18, in <module>
    rows = tbody.find("tr")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

So then I tried just selecting the rows straight up with `soup.find('tr')`.

This results in a `NavigableString` error. What else can I try to retrieve the info in a paired fashion?

Comment: You have messed among table elements- try this code!

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the page source and search for `tbody`, you will get 0 results, so that could be the cause of the first problem. It seems like Wikipedia uses a custom `<table class="wikitable sortable">` and does not specify `tbody`.

For your second problem, you need to be using `find_all` and not `find` because find just returns the first `tr`. So instead you want

```
rows = soup.find_all("tr")
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_average_elevation"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')


countries = []
altitudes = []

for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.find_all('td')
    country= col[0].text.strip()
    elevation = float(''.join(map(unicode.strip,col[1].text.split("m")[0])).replace(',',''))
    countries.append(country)
    altitudes.append(elevation)

print countries,'\n',altitudes
```